# Javascript Object - Use a variable that is defined in the object before it's creation

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve this?

```
var people = Array();

people.push({
    name: "John",
    height_in_cm : 190,
    height_in_inches : this.height_in_cm * 0.39
});
```

This is not working. It's obvious that the object is not yet created. Are there any tricks on getting this to work?

Comment: You can create a type `Person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just declare the object first and then push it:

```
var people = [];

var obj = {
  name: "John",
  height_in_cm : 190
};
obj.height_in_inches = obj.height_in_cm * .39;

people.push(obj);
```

Depending on your case you could also create a "Person" object/class:

```
var person = (function personModule() {
  function Person(props) {
    this.name = props.name;
    this.height_in_cm = props.height_in_cm;
    this.height_in_inches = this.height_in_cm * .39;
  }

  Person.prototype = {...}; // public methods if necessary

  return function(props) {
    return new Person(props);
  }
}());

var people = [];
people.push(person({ name: 'John', height_in_cm: 190 }));

console.log(people[0].height_in_inches); //=> 74.1
```

Comment: Thanks. Person class is what I need :)